# Como encerrar dos elementos en un div? - jquery

Tags: html, jquery, div

Tengo varias secciones con la estructura similar:

```
<div class="padre">
    <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
    <div class="title heading-section"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>

<div class="padre">
    <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
    <div class="title heading-section"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>

<div class="padre">
    <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
    <div class="title heading-section"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
```

Lo que necesito es tener esta estructura en cada una de las secciones:

```
<div class="padre">
    <div class="wrapper d-flex"> //Agregar este div en cada sección
        <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
        <div class="title heading-section"></div>
    </div>
   <div class="description"></div>
 </div>
```

Intenté usando **wrapAll** de jquery de esta forma:

```
$('.solution-heading').wrapAll("<div class='wrapper d-flex' />");
```

pero lo que hizo fue encerrar todos los div que tienen la clase solution-heading en  la misma seccion por lo que tuve:

```
<div class="padre">
    <div class="wrapper d-flex"> //Se unieron todos los div **.icon/.title**
        <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
        <div class="title heading-section"></div>
        <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
        <div class="title heading-section"></div>
        <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
        <div class="title heading-section"></div>
    </div>
   <div class="description"></div>
 </div>
```

Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es ir poniendo el wrapAll uno por uno por cada padre.

```js
$('.padre').each(function(){
  $('.heading-section', this).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper d-flex' />");
});
console.log(document.querySelector("section").innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<div class="padre">
    <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
    <div class="title heading-section"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>

<div class="padre">
    <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
    <div class="title heading-section"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>

<div class="padre">
    <div class="icon heading-section"></div>
    <div class="title heading-section"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
</section>
```